# 'function: redefinition; different basic types' error in C with macro

Tags: c, visual-c++, macros

I'm pretty new to C and I'm trying to do a simple ASSERT macro but I keep getting a redefinition error when trying to compile with msvc on Windows. All I'm trying to do is:

```
void bgz_error() {
    __debugbreak();
};

#define BGZ_ASSERT(condition) \
do  \
{ \
    if(!(condition)) \ 
        bgz_error(); \
} while (0)
```

And I get an error message stating:

```
..\source\win64_main.c(19): error C2371: 'bgz_error': redefinition; different basic types
..\source\win64_main.c(11): note: see declaration of 'bgz_error'
```

This is the only place where I'm defining bgz_error. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Full code currently:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <Windows.h>

#define invlid_code_path __debugbreak()

void bgz_error() {
    __debugbreak();
};

#define BGZ_ASSERT(condition) \
do  \
{ \
    if(!(condition)) \ 
        bgz_error(); \
} while (0)  

void __stdcall WinMainCRTStartup()
{
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
    
    //Set scheduler granularity to help ensure we are able to put thread to sleep by the amount of time specified and no longer
    UINT desired_scheduler_granularity_ms = 1;
    if(timeBeginPeriod(desired_scheduler_granularity_ms) == TIMERR_NOERROR)//Error when trying to set windows granularity!"
    {

    }
    
    WNDCLASS window_properties = {0};
    window_properties.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; //TODO: Check if OWNDC/HREDRAW/VEDRAW matter
    window_properties.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
    window_properties.lpszClassName = "My Window";
    window_properties.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);

    if(ResiterClass(&window_properties))
    {
        DWORD window_styles = WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MASIMIZEBOX;
        RECT rect = (RECT){ 0, 0, (LONG)1280, (LONG)720 };
        BOOL success = AdjustWindowRectEx(&rect, window_styles, false, 0);

        if(NOT success)
            invalid_code_path;
    }
    

    int result = 0;
    ExitProcess(result);
}
```

Comment: Please try to include a proper [mre] to show us. Which line is line 11, which line is line 19?

Comment: Where are you *using* `BGZ_ASSERT`? If that piece of code does not "see" the declaration of `bgz_error`, it would be assumed as `int bgz_error()`, leading to redefinition error.

Comment: Right now, I'm not using it anywhere in order to figure out the problem since I still get the error when I remove it from my code. I've updated my post with all code.

Comment: You have a space after a backslash before a newline: `if(!(condition)) \ <-- right here`.  Remove it.

Comment: Wow, that was it. Thank you!!!! Blah, so annoying.